# How do I get for loop to print the equation for each value

Tags: python, for-loop

How do I get for loop to print the equation for each value (1, 2, etc.) Instead of just the final value 10 times. How to print distance at every second.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In order to best help you, we need the following:
1) Code in code block form that can be copy pasted for reproducibility
2) A description of the solution you've already tried
3) An explanation of your goal along with a detailed question.

Comment: I'm guessing that you might want a `print(d)` statement before your `return d` statement (which should have its indent level reduced by one).

Comment: Take the time to learn how to post to SO. Pictures of text are not good form. The post editor has easy to use icons for common mark-up such as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `t` with `seconds` in your calculation of d.
As it is, you are calculating `d` t-times with t**2. As far as I understand, you want to calculate it t-times but print the distance after every second. So t has to be replaced with the variable you called `seconds`

And then either print in your function `fallingDistance`. Or call your function t-times and print the result in your `main()`